# Random number generating using JSP servlets

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I want generate a unique number which is not exist in my database using jsp and servlets

Comment: Really?  If you ask nicely, @HovercraftFullOfEels might let you ride his pony.

Comment: hey @user3378330, look at my post...

Answer (score 2):

servlet code to generate random numbers as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.*;

/**
* Servlet implementation class SampleRandomNumber
*/
public class SampleRandomNumber extends HttpServlet
{
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
response.setContentType(“text/html”);
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

out.println(“Result is “+(int)(((Math.random())*6)+1)); // random number With in 6 except 0.

}
}
```

You can use java.util.Random, Use nextInt() method and simply add 1000 to it, if you want it to be starting from 1000 , you can simply take first no as 1000

```
<c:set var="rand">
<%= java.lang.Math.round(java.lang.Math.random() * 2) %>
</c:set>
```

Later you can check for ${rand mod 2 == 0} and ${rand mod 2 == 1} to get your desired output.

Comment: bt i want compare this number to database for check it is unique or not ..
if it's not  generate again otherwise it will show on page

Comment: @user3378330, what are telling what if you want to say in the tittle.

Comment: @user3378330, now what you want first, tell me clearly stackflow with you.

Comment: i want generate random number and compare it to database if number is exist that i will again generate the number otherwise not

Comment: @user3378330, look at my update anwser.

Answer (score 0):

You could try sequences for generates unique numbers in ordered way in your database.see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-sequences.htm)

Using java this [thread](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/oracle-java-jdbc-get-primary-key-insert-sql/) might help you..

to generate using java

```
public void randomNumberGeneration {
    int a = 25173, b = 13849, m = 32768;
    Double[] X_ = new Double[100];
    X_[0] = 0.5;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        X_[i] = (a * X_[i - 1] + b) % m;
        X_[i] = X_[i] / m;
        System.out.println("X_[" + i + "] = " + X_[i]);
    }
}
```

Once the value has been generated , write JDBC statements to insert it in DB . 
Use a boolean field to validate it , if the number is same . Call the method again

Hope it helps !!

Comment: i want use java no database programming

Comment: Do you want to generate a random number ?

Comment: yes i want random and unique number s

Comment: above code generates the random number , but if you need it be unique .  a field should be created with `unique` constraint in database . so that you can have your values uniquely